# What is the congruence class of a complex number modulo a prime?

Tags: complex-numbers, congruences

If we are given a complex number $a+bi$, modulo a prime $p$, in the form of the two integers $a$ and $b$, can we say which fractions in the form $\frac{c_1}{c_2} + \frac{d_1}{d_2}i$ are equivalent to this value?  In other words, we have $a$, $b$, and $p$, and I want to find all fractions that are equivalent to $a+bi$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @Crostul:  It means that $0 \le a < p$ and $0 \le b < p$.  I'm guessing I can find what makes $(a+bi)(e+fi)=1 \bmod p$, and then make conclusions about $e+fi$.  This is not homework, by the way.

Comment: Ok, so you are working in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(p)$: this may be a field or not depending on $p$. Anyway, "fractions modulo $p$" are not well defined in this context.

Comment: @Crostul:  Hmmm...  That's unfortunate.  I know that Mathematica was able to return fractions when I asked for the real portion of reciprocals, at least for the few examples that I tried.  What I'm really after is some type of ring (or construct) that allows powering, multiplication, and addition/subtraction of complex numbers defined as fractions for the real and imaginary components.  Is there anything that you could suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to have $\frac{c1}{c_2}\equiv c_1 c_2^{-1}\equiv a \pmod p$. If you choose $c_1$ you compute $c_2\equiv c_1 a^{-1} \pmod p $ and if you specify $c_2$ you simply compute $c_1 = c_2 a \pmod p$.  Same procedure for $d_1,d_2, b$